# Centering floated divs

Tags: html, css

I have two divs with center content in them, and I cant get said divs to align center within their parent container. I have tried

```
#section_4{
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    padding-top: 6em;

    #left_half, #right_half{
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: none;

    }
```

}

But that just pushes the right one to the right and leaves a gap in the middle.

http://jsfiddle.net/hL2g1p9t/

Comment: Remove the floats and the inline block elements will center

Comment: I just saw that I have `float: left` on one of them.  thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `float` properties. Using `inline-block` and `margin: 0 auto` should be all you need.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/oaj42we4/)